# Problema filosofos C#

Tags: c#, hilos

Estoy realizando el típico problema de los filósofos en C#. 
Ya lo tengo resuelto, en mi caso he creado la clase Filosofo para hacer el método comer, pero no sé cómo hacer para que cada filosofo coma 5 veces y luego se levante.

He probado a hacer un while antes del if (lockTaken) y añadiendo 1 a numComidas o sino poniéndolo donde inicio las tareas, pero me salta error o no devuelve absolutamente nada. Pienso que es una tontería, pero soy incapaz de verlo.

Alguien qué me pueda echar una mano? Adjunto mi código.

Gracias!

```
    class Program
    {
        //Creamos los 5 filosofos y los 5 tenedores
        public static Filosofo[] filo = new Filosofo[5];
        public static object[] tenedores = new object[5];

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int numFilosofos = 5;
            for (int i = 0; i < numFilosofos; i++)
            {
                tenedores[i] = new object();
            }

            filo[0] = new Filosofo(0, numFilosofos - 1, 0);

            for (int i = 1; i < numFilosofos; i++)
            {
                filo[i] = new Filosofo(i, i - 1, i);
            }

            //Creamos las instancias de las tareas
            var t1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(filo[0].comer));
            var t2 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(filo[1].comer));
            var t3 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(filo[2].comer));
            var t4 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(filo[3].comer));
            var t5 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(filo[4].comer));

            //Iniciamos las tareas
            t1.Start(filo[0]);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            t2.Start(filo[2]);
            t3.Start(filo[3]);
            t4.Start(filo[1]);
            t5.Start(filo[4]);
            var s = Console.ReadLine();
            while (s != "exit")
            {
                s = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    class Filosofo
    {
        //Atributos
        int indice;
        int palilloIzq;
        int palilloDrc;
        int numComidas;

        //Constructor
        public Filosofo(int indice, int palilloIzq, int palilloDrc)
        {
            this.indice = indice;
            this.palilloIzq = palilloIzq;
            this.palilloDrc = palilloDrc;
            this.numComidas = 0;
        }

        //Metodo comer
        public void comer(object param)
        {
            Filosofo filoComer = (Filosofo)param;
            bool lockTaken = false;

            Monitor.TryEnter(Program.tenedores[filoComer.palilloIzq], 1000, ref lockTaken);

            if (lockTaken)
            {
                try
                {
                    lockTaken = false;
                    Console.WriteLine("El Filosofo {0} coge el palillo izquierdo {1} dcho {2} y ha comido {3} veces.", indice, filoComer.palilloIzq, filoComer.palilloDrc, numComidas);
                    numComidas++;

                    Monitor.TryEnter(Program.tenedores[filoComer.palilloDrc], 1000, ref lockTaken);

                    if (lockTaken)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("El filosofo {0} coge el palillo derecho {1}", indice, filoComer.palilloDrc);
                            Console.WriteLine("El filosofo {0} está comiendo", indice);
                            //Thread.Sleep(1000);

                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            Monitor.Exit(Program.tenedores[filoComer.palilloDrc]);
                            Console.WriteLine("El filosofo {0} deja el palillo derecho", indice);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("El filósofo {0} está hambriento.", indice);
                    }

                }
                finally
                {
                    Monitor.Exit(Program.tenedores[filoComer.palilloIzq]);
                    Console.WriteLine("El filosofo {0} deja el palillo izquierdo", indice);
                    Console.WriteLine("El filosofo {0} deja de comer", indice);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("El filósofo {0} está hambriento", indice);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No esta funcionando porque no estas haciendo que coman 5 veces, solo usas el for para rellenar los 5 filosofos y nada mas. Luego creas un hilo para cada uno y lo estas ejecutando una sola vez por cada filosofo.

Comment: Lo sé, he probado varias veces meter un while para que repita, pero aun y todo solo me lo hace una vez. La verdad que me he bloqueado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si comprendí bien el problema que tenes, pero probaste hacer algo como:

```
if (filoComer.numComidas == 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine("El filosofo {0} esta lleno y se levanta", filoComer.indice);
}
```

De esta manera es donde verificas si está lleno, por lo que vi en tu codigo nunca te fijas cuando comió 5 veces.

El resultado final sería:

```
//Metodo comer
        public void comer(object param)
        {
            Filosofo filoComer = (Filosofo)param;
            bool lockTaken = false;

            Monitor.TryEnter(Program.tenedores[filoComer.palilloIzq], 1000, ref lockTaken);

            if (lockTaken)
            {
                try
                {
                    lockTaken = false;
                    Console.WriteLine("El Filosofo {0} coge el palillo izquierdo {1} dcho {2} y ha comido {3} veces.", filoComer.indice, filoComer.palilloIzq, filoComer.palilloDrc, filoComer.numComidas /*--->> aca indicas el num de comidas del filosofo*/ );
                    filoComer.numComidas++; //--->> aca le sumas el numero de comidas al filosofo


                    Monitor.TryEnter(Program.tenedores[filoComer.palilloDrc], 1000, ref lockTaken);

                    if (lockTaken)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("El filosofo {0} coge el palillo derecho {1}", filoComer.indice, filoComer.palilloDrc);
                            Console.WriteLine("El filosofo {0} está comiendo", filoComer.indice);
                            //Thread.Sleep(1000);

                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            Monitor.Exit(Program.tenedores[filoComer.palilloDrc]);
                            Console.WriteLine("El filosofo {0} deja el palillo derecho", filoComer.indice);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("El filósofo {0} está hambriento.", filoComer.indice);
                    }

                }
                finally
                {
                    Monitor.Exit(Program.tenedores[filoComer.palilloIzq]);
                    Console.WriteLine("El filosofo {0} deja el palillo izquierdo", filoComer.indice);
                    Console.WriteLine("El filosofo {0} deja de comer", filoComer.indice);

                    //if para ver si el filosofo está lleno
                    if (filoComer.numComidas == 5)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("El filosofo {0} esta lleno y se levanta", filoComer.indice);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("El filósofo {0} está hambriento", filoComer.indice);
            }
        }
```

Tambien le cambie el "indice" por "filoComer.indice" y el numcomidas++ por "filoComer.numComidas".